# Circular generic types in inheritance - why does it work?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, circular-dependency

Consider the following:

```
public class EntityBase<TEntity>
{
    public virtual void DoSomethingWhereINeedToKnowAboutTheEntityType()
    {
    }
}

public class PersonEntity : EntityBase<PersonEntity>
{
    public override void DoSomethingWhereINeedToKnowAboutTheEntityType()
    {
    }
}
```

I added this into code and ran it and it worked ok, but I'm surprised that I can inherit a class who's definition is based on the inheriting class.

When I tried it I was expecting either it not to compile, or to fail once actually called.

You can do something similar with an interface:

```
public interface IEntityBase<TEntity>
{}

public class PersonEntity : IEntityBase<PersonEntity>
{}
```

I've actually switched my code from the former to the later, using the interface, but I'm still curious why this works.

Comment: Notice that you do this all the time when you implement IComparable<T> and IEquatable<T> on an object.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo. TY for the edit - mixing my vb and c#!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm surprised that I can inherit a class who's definition is based on the inheriting class.

Careful - what you're inheriting is a class whose definition **involves an arbitrary `Type`**, is all. All of these are legal:

```
class O : EntityBase<object>
class S : EntityBase<String>
class Q : EntityBase<Q>
```

All you've said in the definition of `EntityBase` is that `TEntity` should be a **type** - well, `PersonEntity` is a type, isn't it? So why shouldn't it be eligible to be a `TEntity`? No reason why not - so it works.

You might be concerned about the *order* of definitions, but remember that within the unit of compilation, everything gets defined 'at once' - there's no sense in which `PersonEntity` needs to be compiled 'before' anything else (including itself!) can refer to it. Indeed, you're even allowed

```
class A : EntityBase<B>
class B : EntityBase<A>
```

for which no conceivable 'order of compilation' could work, **if** such a thing were needed.

Comment: This is the answer that's laid it out best for me. I use Generics all the time, am a big fan, but was getting my head in a muddle. (Its Friday!)

Answer (score 4):

It works because there's no reason why it wouldn't work. `EntityBase<PersonEntity>` doesn't inherit from `PersonEntity`, it merely references the type. There's no technical problem with a base class knowing about its own derived class. This also works (even though this specific example is a bad idea):

```
public class A
{
    public B AsB()
    {
        return this as B;
    }
}


public class B : A
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example is the generic interface `IComparable<T>`. Usually, you implement it like this:

```
class MyClass : IComparable<MyClass> {/*...*/}
```

This implementation of the generic template is just saying that `MyClass` objects can compare to other `MyClass` objects. As you can see, there is no problem with the mental model. I can very well understand the concept of a class whose objects can compare between them without knowing anything else about the class.

The main point here is that template parameters are just used by the generic class or interface, but they need not be related by inheritance at all. `IComparable<MyClass>` does not inherit from `MyClass`. So there is no circularity.